# In SceneKit, is it possible to make imported animation excepting object current position as origin?

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit, blender

We imported an animation from Blender into SceneKit.
Animation includes very simple movement on xy plane because we are just testing it at the moment.
We loaded it with following code;

```
    let importedDae = SCNScene(named: "animated.scn")!
    let node = importedDae.rootNode.childNode(
    withName: "Cube", recursively: true)!.clone()
    self.headAnimationPlayer = headNode.animationPlayer(forKey: "Cube_CubeAction_transform")!
    let animation = headAnimationPlayer.animation
```

Then we added it to our object with

```
    ourObject.addAnimation(self.anime, forKey: "Cube_CubeAction_transform")
```

as expected animation is started immediately.
But there was a problem animation moved object
to the position (0,0,0) then made the animation.

We have created animation in Blender around position (0,0,0) it is logical.
But our object is dynamic and could be anywhere when animation added.

We want animation to use our object's current position as origin and make animation 
around it. Is that possible ?

Comment: If we use two nodes for our object on top of each other and if we add animation at second one with geometry it works fine. We use first one to move around and second one for animation but this is complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in a comment, using a intermediate node to place the object in the scene is one way to solve this.

You can also have a look at the [`additive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/capropertyanimation/1412493-additive) property of `CAPropertyAnimation` (as superclass of `CAKeyframeAnimation`) but to use it you might have to decompose the animation.